# It can't support CartesianChartModel support in PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf

Why PrimeFaces 5.1 doesn't have CartesianChartModel? When I update PrimeFaces from 4.0 t0 5.1, it can't work. The CartesianChartModel can't support now. Does anyone know about that or give me one example for that? Does it have substitute one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While your post is not really complete enought to be sure that the following will help in your case. I too have just upgraded to Primefaces 5.1 and found that my line chart using the CartesianChartModel no longer worked.

This is what I used to have:

```xhtml
<p:lineChart value="#{myManagedBean.chartModel}" />
```

Primefaces 5.1 has deprecated the older tags for the charts and I had to change my XHTML file to the following to make it work:

```xhtml
<p:chart type="line" model="#{myManagedBean.chartModel}" />
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I migrated from primefaces 5.0 to 5.1 and got the same problem.

Then I changed the tag from
`<p:barChart value="#{bean.chartModel}"/>`

to
`<p:chart type="bar" model="#{bean.chartModel}"/>`

And then I got a ClassCastException:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.chart.BarChartModel`

So I change the implementation in the managedBean from `new CartesianChartModel()` to `new HorizontalBarChartModel()` and it works as well.